# Solving symbolic equation for fraction of variables

Tags: symbolic

Suppose there is an equation like this (overly simplified example):

```
eqn1 = ui - ua r1 / (r1 + r2) == 0
```

How can I get Mathematica to "solve" the equation
in terms of:

```
eqn2 = v == ua / ui
```

i.e. have Mathematica deliver `v == 1 + r2 / r1` as a result?
Despite googling I cannot find the proper way (tried equation system, Eliminate, LinearSolve, ...). Thanks in advance - Rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) with [`Eliminate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate):

```
Solve[
    Eliminate[{ui-ua r1/(r1+r2)==0,v==ua/ui}, ua],
    v
]
```

> {{v -> (r1 + r2)/r1}}

Comment: works like a charm, thx. Shouldn't the 2nd parameter on Eliminate be the list {ua , ui} rather than {ua} ?

Comment: @RobertGIDS. With only two equations, I think it's safer to try to eliminate just one variable.

Answer (score 5):

Although not currently documented, you can include in `Solve` a list of variables to be eliminated.

```
Solve[{ui - ua r1/(r1 + r2) == 0, v == ua/ui}, v, {ua}][[1]] // Expand

(* {v -> 1 + r2/r1} *)
```

Comment: Thx, this works indeed - though I'm confused as the Language Reference designates Solve's 3rd parameter as "domain", e.g. Integers, Reals, Complexes - it never occured to me that "domain" could also be used for variable elimination. I guess not many folks are aware of this context - so kudos to you for pointing this out.
I'd appreciate if you kindly comment on this "[ [1] ]" construct - what is it's meaning ?

Comment: @RobertGIDS. - As I stated, the use of a list of variable to be eliminated is **not** documented. It was a long time ago and presumably still functions to maintain backward compatibility. Consequently, the third argument here is not being used to specify a domain. The `[[1]]` takes the first element of a list (see `Part`). In this case it removes an extra set of list brackets.